# Custom fonts not showing in Chrome

Tags: html, css, font-face

I have a some custom fonts installed on Ubuntu 18.04 server.  They render correctly in Firefox, but not in Chrome.  After research, I found an answer that says to include a separate @font-face in my css.

My current @font-face is:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: (font-name);
    src: local(font-name);
}
```

They say I should add another @font-face like this:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: (font-name);
    src: url('../font-name.ttf');
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is that answer correct, or is there another way to get custom fonts to load in Chrome?
2. What is the path to the font cache in Ubuntu 18.04?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you could just use the shorthand.

```
@font-face{
    font-family: (font-name);
    src: local(font-name), 
         url('../font-name.ttf');
}
```

This will instruct the browser to prioritize using the user's installed copy of the font is used if available (local), falling back to downloading a copy (url) of the font if it's not found on the user's device. The url value can be either an relative value or absolute path -- in this case the font file must be in the parent directory of the css file.

Comment: I think the url in the second instance needs to be the full path to the font-cache in Ubuntu.  You show it as just ../font-name.ttf').  Is that enough?

Comment: Why wouldn't that be?

Comment: I read that in another example.  I'll try your code and see what happens.  Thanks for the idea.

Comment: No, that doesn't work.  I think I need the full path in Ubuntu.  I don't know what that is so I'll have to find out.